# Should I avoid multibit code starting with 0 (zero) for huffman code?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, huffman-code

When I use Huffman greedy algorithm to construct the binary tree, I am getting the following, if all the four alphabets are equally probable:

- 00
- 01
- 10
- 11

The problem is, my program see 00 and 01 as only 0 and 1.  Should I restrict the length of the code starting with 0 (zero) to 1 (one)?  What data type should use to store the huffman code or its individual bits?

Comment: what do you mean by *my program see 00 and 01 as only 0 and 1*?

Comment: If I store each of the four values (viz., 00, 01, 10, 11), in an integer array at the end of Huffman code generation, what I get back during look-up are 0, 1, 10, 11 respectively.  (Let us assume that the actual characters 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' are stored in another array of type character.  The indices 0, 1, 2, 3 will be used for the look-up).

Comment: that is right, so 0 is 00, and 1 is 01.  what's the problem?

Comment: 1 (code for 'a') is a prefix of 11 (code for 'd').  Huffman code is all about prefix free code.  Therefore should I preclude 01 (and in turn preclude 1) as a possible Huffman code, in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If your "program see 00 and 01 as only 0 and 1", then your program have bug.

For four equiprobable symbols, the code would indeed be 00, 01, 10, and 11.  That means you need to look for all of those bits when decoding.  When decoding you pull the bit on the left first.  So you get a 0.  That means the code is either 00 or 01.  Then you pull the next bit.  It's a 1.  So now you have the complete code 01.  You emit the corresponding symbol, and then start over.

It's easier to see for the more typical case where the probabilities are not equal and the codes have different lengths.  Consider this code:

```
a - 0
b - 10
c - 110
d - 111
```

To decode you start pulling bits from the stream.  The first bit is 1.  Now you know that it must be a, b, c, or d.  Now you pull another 1.  You have it down to c or d.  You pull a 0, so now you know its d.  You start from the beginning with the next bit.

Until you start pulling bits and narrowing down choices, you don't know the length of the code.  You will know the length of the code once you have decoded it.

Comment: How do I convey the size information of each Huffman code to the look-up function?  If the value of 'a' is the binary number "0000 0000 0000 0000" (say, stored in a char variable in C), how will the look-up function decide the size of the Huffman code, especially since Huffman code is all about variable length codes.

Comment: You determine the length of the Huffman code when you have finished decoding it, not before.

Comment: What do you mean by "determine the length of the Huffman code after you have finished decoding it"?  Can you explain with an example?